# Method not changing array in main

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods

First time posting here but I have a question in regards to a method not changing the values in the array it is given.

I thought arrays were passed by reference and thus changing the array in the method would change it in the array. However this is not working for me and I have no idea why.

My code is below. The method that is not working is `readFile()`

```
package StudentsGrades;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class StudentsGrades {

    public static void main(String [] args ) {
    int numberOfLines = 0;
    String fileName = "";

    fileName = "marks_file.csv";
    //Obtain the number of lines in the given csv.
    numberOfLines = getNumberLines(fileName);
    System.out.println(numberOfLines);

    //initialise the arrays that the data will be stored in.
    double[] gradesArray = new double[numberOfLines];
    String[] studentsArray = new String[numberOfLines];

    if (numberOfLines > 0) {
        readFile(studentsArray, gradesArray, numberOfLines, fileName);
    }
    System.out.println(studentsArray[4]);
}
public static int getNumberLines (String importFile)  {
    int numLines = 0;
    try {
        FileReader fnol = new FileReader(importFile);
        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(fnol);

        while (lnr.readLine() != null ) {
            numLines++;
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
        System.out.println("The file cannot be found");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid");
    }
    return numLines;
}
public static void readFile (String [] studentsArray, double[] gradesArray, int numLines, String fileName ) {
    try {
        String lineData = null;
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String currentLine = "";

        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null ) {
            //Store the current Line in a string
            String[] lineDataArray = currentLine.split("\\s*,\\s*");
            //To index its position in the array
            int index = 0;
            //System.out.println(lineDataArray[1]);
            studentsArray[index] = lineDataArray[0];
            gradesArray[index] = Double.parseDouble(lineDataArray[1]);
            System.out.println("Student: " + studentsArray[index]
            + " Grade: " + gradesArray[index]);
            index++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unexpected value in file.");
    }

}
}
```

The output

> Student: Christopher Lee Grade: 54.0
>   Student: Stanley Wright Grade: 90.5
>   Student: Oliver Stewart Grade: 75.8
>   Student: Jessica Chang Grade: 34.65
>   Student: Adam Bweon Grade: 66.6
>   Student: Chrissy Yeo Grade: 88.9
>   null

As you can see the last value is `null` and that is when I try and print a value from the array within `Main`.

Comment: btw: You should close all those readers!

Answer (score 5):

Place `int index=0;` outside the loop.

If you want to fill the arrays you need to declare `index` before the loop.
Since now it is inside the loop, it is redeclared everytime and initialized to 0.
So, index is always 0 when you use it, and you overwrite the values.